# Example of building a classifying space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, classifying-spaces

I'm reading some things about algebraic topology, and they mention the classifying space of a group $G$ as $BG$, but they doesn't build one, so I want to ask if someone knows where can I find the way to create one classifying space $BG$ from a given group $G$.

Comment: You can also find the Milnor construction in Fibre Bundles book by Dale Husemoller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his paper [*Construction of Universal Bundles, II*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970012?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Milnor constructed a universal bundle $EG \to BG$ for any topological group $G$ using the notion of [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)). It is now called the [Milnor (join) construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Milnor+construction). Aside from the original paper, this construction can be found, for example, in Appendix B of *Spin Geometry* by Lawson & Michelsohn.

Comment: Now that I have read that part of the article of Milnor, I understand that he makes $n$ copies of the group and then he calls it $E_n$, then he operates $E_n\times G\longrightarrow G$ and identifies the elements $e,e'$. My question is if $e\in E_n$ and $e'\in E_n$ and next does a quotient of the possible images obtained from $R$ of $E_n$. What I understood is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Note that space $X$ having a contractible (universal) cover is a $B\pi_1(X)$ i.e. a model for $K(\pi_1(X),1)$-space. This is because when $G$ is discrete a principal $G$-bundle is the same as a regular covering.

Thus, when $G$ is discrete other than Milnor construction you can construct $BG$ by the usual construction of $K(G,n)$-spaces (see Hatcher). Briefly, take a presentation of $G$ build a CW-complex $X$ with $\pi_1(X)=G$ and kill higher homotopy groups by attaching cells.