# Constructing $X$ with $π_1(X) ≅ ℝ$

Tags: homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a connected CW-complex with $π_1(X) ≅ ℝ$, $π_n(X) ≅ 0$ for $n ≥ 2$.

Can someone help me obtain a description or construction of $X$?

$ΩX$ has connected components in correspondence with $ℝ$, but also **the group structure should match as well**.

Comment: For any group $G$, there is a space $BG$, called the classifying space, satisfying the conditions you want. You can read about constructions of classifying spaces in multiple places, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1693232/42781 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space or https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+space.

Comment: For any group $G$, we have a presentation of $G$ by its generators and relations. First attach as many copies of one cell as the cardinality of the set of generators of $G$. Then attach 2-cells according to the relations along the boundaries of the 1-cells. This will give you a connected CW-complex $X$ with fundamental group $G$. For $G=\mathbb{R}$, we have the reals on the intervals $[0,1)$ as the generating set and we have infinitely many relations among them.